# Not reading records in correctly from TFRecord file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm new to Tensorflow and have used the `build_image_data.py` file and tutorial found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/README.md#how-to-construct-a-new-dataset-for-retraining).

I've built a small convolutional neural network to classify my own data set with 2 classes. When I ran my code I was getting errors related to a reshape op, basically my images are `72x72 RGB` pixels. So the shape I defined was `[72, 72, 3]`. I was then getting `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 14040 values, but the requested shape has 15552`. Now it should be `15552` values I thought as `72*72*3 = 15552`. If there was only `14040` then perhaps there's something wrong with my image?

I took the images myself or got them from Google, and used a java program to resize them all to `72x72` pixels.

I've tried to `eval()` the image as they come into the model but there is no output and the whole thing just hangs for like a minute until I shut it off.

```py
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

filename = "../../dataset/traffic_sign/train-00000-of-00001"

# convert filename to a queue for an input pipeline.
filenameQ = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=None)

# OUTPUT = AttributeError: 'FIFOQueue' object has no attribute 'eval'
print(filenameQ.eval())

# object to read records
recordReader = tf.TFRecordReader()

# read the full set of features for a single example
key, fullExample = recordReader.read(filenameQ)

# NO OUTPUT: program hangs
print(fullExample.eval())

# parse the full example into its' component features.
features = tf.parse_single_example(
fullExample,
features={
    'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/colorspace': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/channels': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value='')
})

# now we are going to manipulate the label and image features

label = features['image/class/label']
image_buffer = features['image/encoded']

# Decode the jpeg
with tf.name_scope('decode_jpeg', [image_buffer], None):
# decode turns tensor of type string. 0-D the JPEG encoded image
# to tensor of type uint8. 3-D with shape [height, width, channels]
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)


image = tf.reshape(image, [HEIGHT, WIDTH, NUM_CHANNELS])
image = tf.to_float(image, "ToFloat")

# re-define label as a "one-hot" vector
# it will be [0,1] or [1,0] here.
# This approach can easily be extended to more classes
label = tf.one_hot(label - 1, NUM_CLASSES, dtype=tf.int64)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
# NO OUTPUT: program hangs
print(label.eval())
```

When I created the TFRecord file I followed the example [here](https://agray3.github.io/2016/11/29/Demystifying-Data-Input-to-TensorFlow-for-Deep-Learning.html) with a label file `mylabels.txt` containing `go` and `stop` and my directory structure is as follows:

```py
traffic_sign/train/go/go*.jpeg
traffic_sign/train/stop/stop*.jpeg
traffic_sign/validation/go/go*.jpeg
traffic_sign/validation/stop/stop*.jpeg
```

I used the command:

```py
python build_image_data.py --train_directory=./train --output_directory=./  \
--validation_directory=./validation --labels_file=mylabels.txt   \
--train_shards=1 --validation_shards=1 --num_threads=1
```

The records file was created and just contains lots of bytes.

I have no clue how to solve this, I don't know whether I've made a mistake creating the dataset. But the image should be `72x72x3` so I don't know why there's a tensor in my model with `14040` values. And the fact I can't seem to evaluate a tensor and the program just hangs isn't allowing me to debug.

Help MUCH appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a rogue image in my data set which was `72x65`... hence the 14040 result. I replaced with a `72x72` image and its working now